# Error en IF anidado (batch)

Tags: cmd, batch

Hace poco, cree un simple script, solo para ver como funcionaban los IFs. El problema es que ahora lo he intentado usar con `GOTO`, pero el segundo IF no funciona, se detiene la ejecución del programa.

El código:

```
SET /P select="Select function (format: X): "

CLS

IF %select%==N (

   ECHO Name: STH
   GOTO :end

) ELSE (

  GOTO :second

)

REM Este es el IF que no funciona

:second

IF %select%==T (
   ECHO STH
   GOTO :end

) ELSE (

  GOTO :third

:end

PING -n 1 localhost>NUL

PAUSE>NUL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que se puede observar es que al segundo `if` le falta un cierre de paréntesis.

Luego, no existe la sección de la etiqueta `:third` referenciada en `GOTO :third`.

Con esos dos pequeños cambios, el *script* parece funcionar bien.

```
@echo off
SET /P select="Select function (format: X): "

CLS

IF %select%==N (
   ECHO seccion: N
   ECHO Name: STH
   GOTO :end
) ELSE (
  GOTO :second
)

:second

IF %select%==T (
   ECHO seccion: T
   ECHO STH
   GOTO :end
) ELSE (
  GOTO :third
)

:third 
  ECHO seccion: Otros
  ECHO tercero
  goto :end

:end
PING -n 1 localhost>NUL
PAUSE>NUL
```

Dicho esto, estás utilizando `goto`, por lo tanto, no son realmente `if's` anidados, pero podrías anidarlos algo así:

```
if condicion1 (
  instruccion1
) else (
  if condicion2 (
    instruccion2
  ) else (
    instruccion3
  )
)
```

Comment: Gracias!! Sí, se resolvió